# Как подобрать просто решение для теста ниши?

Tags: php, cms

Подскажите плиз, хочу протестировать одну идею с минимальными трудо/финансо-затратами.
Нужен сайт с регистрацией, личным кабинетом (что-бы написать пиьсмо администратору) и возможностью пополнять баланс аккаунта.

Как / на чём это проще всего реализовать? Я фронтэндер, из cms работал только с WP, натягивал свои верстки.

Можно ли обойтись "малой кровью" ?)

Comment: Если вы фронтом занимаетесь, значит знаете `JS`. Делите логику и делайте API. Фронт напишите на React, Anlgular, или что-то иное. Сервер напишите на node.js

Comment: @Mully да вы же понимаете, если пилить с нуля, это долго, хочется найти готовые/полуготовые решения, с моими знаниями с нуля  я буду делать это не меньше месяца. А хочется развернуть какой-то шаблон за несколько дней

Comment: К вашему сожалению прграммирование, оно на то и программировние чтобы вы разрабатывали, и вы не найдете готовых шаблонов сайта, разве что наброски в виде "макетов".